# How to get the difference between a query builder instance and an array of same instance

Tags: php, laravel

How to get the differencce between a query builder instance of a Model table and an array of objects of same model?

```
    foreach ($completed_course_id as $value)
    {
        array_push($completed_courses,DB::table('courses')->where('id', $value)->first()); 
    }
    $courses = Course::all();
    $result =  array_diff($courses, $completed_courses);
```

Passing result as compact returns "array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Course::all()` will return you a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object which provides you [vast amount of helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) to iterate through arrays.

So instead of `array_diff($courses, $completed_courses);`, you would need to first convert the `$courses` to array by calling `$courses->toArray()`:

```
$result = array_diff($courses->toArray(), $completed_courses);
```

---

On a side note, what the code above that is trying to achieve is probably won't going to work since you are doing `array_diff` on a series of objects! It's also inefficient to loop the `$completed_course_id` and query it one by one. I'm assuming your aim here is to retrieve all the incomplete courses. To do this, you can simply use this to replace all of the codes above:

```
$result = DB::table('courses')
    ->whereNotIn('id', $completed_course_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

if using `all()` and `get()` it will return an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. So we need to convert to array using `toArray()` function.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#collections